# How to delete an item in my list view using the items specific delete button?

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I have a listView with a delete button for every item. I would like to be able to delete that Item when the items button is clicked on.

I have tried using .remove (position) and [position] = null but it does not work. I'm not sure if its because I have used a database and cursorAdapter or because I am new to Android Studio and I just don't know what actual variable should go before the .remove. As I'm aware my code it quite messy but it works so far.

```
private void populatelistView() {
            final Cursor res = userDb.getAllRows();
            final String[] fromFeildnames = new String[]{ DatabaseUser.KEY_1, DatabaseUser.KEY_2};
            final int[] toViewIds = new int[]{R.id.textViewNum, R.id.textViewItem};
            final SimpleCursorAdapter myCursorAdaptor;
            myCursorAdaptor = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getBaseContext(), R.layout.item_layout, res, fromFeildnames, toViewIds, 0){
                @Override
                public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
                    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_layout, null, true);
                    delete= (Button)rowView.findViewById(R.id.deleteItem);
                    delete.setTag(position);


                    Cursor cursor = (Cursor) mylist.getItemAtPosition(position);
                    String listName = cursor.getString(1);
                    String displayName = db.getName(listName);

                    TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textViewItem);
                    textView.setText(displayName);
View.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            View parentRow = (View) v.getParent();
                            ListView listView = (ListView) parentRow.getParent();
                            final int position = listView.getPositionForView(parentRow);
                            Cursor cursor = (Cursor) mylist.getItemAtPosition(position);
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Button " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
                    return rowView;
                }
            };
            mylist.setAdapter(myCursorAdaptor);
        }
```

Comment: "but it works so far" is not a good statement. You should first work on modularizing your code, atleast with basic comments. You cannot expect anyone to understand and rewrite the entire answer for you.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, however I am new to coding and am a student so atm as long as it works its fine. I don't want someone to rewrite my code I just want to see if someone knows why certain lines of code I've tried aren't working and want to know if perhaps it is because of my code. Also because I am new I am not sure if it is maybe a problem in Java or Android studio.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try do something like this:

```
myList.remove([INDEX]);
myList.notifyDataSetChanged(); or adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

It should work! If not tell me!

more here:
[How to delete item from listview using button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15239524/how-to-delete-item-from-listview-using-button)

never give up

Comment: Thank you for your kind response. However this does not work as mylist comes up in red and has error saying cannot resolve symbol. (When the button is clicked the toast comes up correctly with the correct position so the rest works).

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why are you putting your `cursor` inside `mylist` when the purpose of using `SimpleCursorAdapter`, you could just get the `cursor` instance by calling `getCursor()` method.

To answer your question, follow below steps:

Create delete method in your `UserDb` class

```
class UserDb {

    void delete(String userId) {
        mSqLiteDatabase.delete(USER_TABLE,
                "id = ?",
                new String[]{userId});
    }
}
```

Set `onClickListener` to your delete button

```
delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int deletePosition = (int) v.getTag();
        cursor.moveToPosition(deletePosition);
        String userId = cursor.getString(1); // I assume this is the user id
        userDb.delete(userId);

        // get the cursor that contains the newest data
        Cursor newestDataCursor = userDb.getAllRows();

        // change your adapter cursor
        myCursorAdaptor.changeCursor(newestDataCursor);

        // tell your adapter that the data has been changed, so it needs to update it's views
        myCursorAdaptor.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});
```

Just for your consideration, you can use

- `RecyclerView` to get a better performance and memory handling.
- `ORM` (Object-Relational Mapping) library like `Room` or even `Firebase` to make your life easier.